# Get name by id in laravel and vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new to laravel and vue js. I would like to show the country name instead of country id. Now, I used `@{{ item.country_id }}` to print the country_id. May I know how to print the country name based on the country id ?

My controller

```
public function index(IndexState $request)
    {
        // create and AdminListing instance for a specific model and
        $data = AdminListing::create(State::class)->processRequestAndGet(
            // pass the request with params
            $request,

            // set columns to query
            ['id', 'name', 'country_id', 'enabled'],

            // set columns to searchIn
            ['id', 'name'],

            function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->with(['country']);

                // add this line if you want to search by author attributes
                $query->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'states.country_id');

                if($request->has('countries')){
                    $query->whereIn('country_id', $request->get('countries'));
                }
            }
        );

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($request->has('bulk')) {
                return [
                    'bulkItems' => $data->pluck('id')
                ];
            }
            return ['data' => $data];
        }

        $states = State::where('country_id');

        return view('admin.state.index', ['data' => $data]);
    }
```

My view

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in collection" :key="item.id" :class="bulkItems[item.id] ? 'bg-bulk' : ''">
        <td class="bulk-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input" :id="'enabled' + item.id" type="checkbox" v-model="bulkItems[item.id]" v-validate="''" :data-vv-name="'enabled' + item.id"  :name="'enabled' + item.id + '_fake_element'" @click="onBulkItemClicked(item.id)" :disabled="bulkCheckingAllLoader">
            <label class="form-check-label" :for="'enabled' + item.id">
            </label>
        </td>

        <td>@{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.country_id }}</td>
        <td>
            <label class="switch switch-3d switch-success">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" v-model="collection[index].enabled" @change="toggleSwitch(item.resource_url, 'enabled', collection[index])">
                <span class="switch-slider"></span>
            </label>
        </td>


        <td>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-spinner btn-info" :href="item.resource_url + '/edit'" title="{{ trans('brackets/admin-ui::admin.btn.edit') }}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                </div>
                <form class="col" @submit.prevent="deleteItem(item.resource_url)">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="{{ trans('brackets/admin-ui::admin.btn.delete') }}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My model

```
class State extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'country_id',
        'enabled',
    
    ];
    
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    
    ];
    
    protected $appends = ['resource_url'];

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function taman() {
        return $this->hasMany(Taman::class);
    }

    /* ************************ ACCESSOR ************************* */

    public function getResourceUrlAttribute()
    {
        return url('/admin/states/'.$this->getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more about the place where you initiate and pass data to `item` variable?

Comment: I just edited the code for my controller. Please have a look.

Comment: I see, you are using Craftable. Can't you find anything helpful in official [document](https://getcraftable.com/docs/7.0/listing)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using craftable.

Comment: I have checked the official documentation but I cannot find anything help.

Comment: I think [this](https://getcraftable.com/docs/7.0/relations) should do it

Comment: try dd($item->country); and check weather it returns you data or not

Comment: `// set columns to searchIn
            ['id', 'name', 'countries.country_name'],`. Add `countries.country_name`, replace with correct country name field and try if there is any different since I don't use Craftable

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I solved the problem by changing the @{{ item.country_id }} to @{{ item.country.name }} in my view.